# UILabel preferredMaxLayoutWidth and wrapping discrepency between iOS 7 and 8

Tags: ios, ios7, ios8, autolayout

I have a table view cell subclass that has three UILabels stacked on top of each other - the top label has `numberOfLines = 0`, the middle one has 3, the bottom has 1. In 99% of the cases iOS 8 works perfectly fine; however, there are some scenarios where, **if in the top label I set some text that is *just* on the point where the label wants to wrap, weird things begin to happen**.

Essentially, the middle label will disappear, or show maybe 0.33pts of its height. Autolayout trace shows there's some ambiguous constraints. Obviously I want to show all the labels and for autolayout to expand the cell based on the content.

My vertical hugging/compression priority on all three labels is 1000/750.

As I said, I can't tell if it's my constraints being wrong, iOS 8 being different to 7 (but intended), or iOS 8 being buggy.

I am setting `preferredMaxLayoutWidth` on all labels in the cell's `layoutSubViews` method to their respective frame widths. I can "fix" this issue by reducing preferredMaxLayoutWidth by 20pts or so - this then causes the "wrap" on the label to alter. It's not really a fix because I can take a character or two out of the text and it'll bug out again because the wrap has altered.

In my `heightForRowAtIndexPath` I have an off-screen cell and do:

```
prototypeCell.bounds = CGRectMake(0, 0, CGRectGetWidth(self.tableView.bounds), CGRectGetHeight(prototypeCell.bounds));
[prototypeCell layoutIfNeeded];
```

One more thing: Using the resizable iPhone I can set the screen width to 320pts and things break, but when I slowly increase the width of the screen, things work again. This is what leads me to believe it's the wrapping on the UILabel.[image: Broken cell][image: Working cell]

I have created a Github project, showing what's going on with the cells/labels:

https://github.com/gbrhaz/BrokenTableViewCells

Comment: If the top label is able to use multiple lines, why is it truncating with the ellipsis? Does it help to set `lineBreakMode` to `NSLineBreakByWordWrapping`?

Comment: That's what I'm confused about. It just doesn't wrap when the text is of a particular size. Word wrapping doesn't fix it, it just cuts off.

Comment: You say you set `preferredMaxLayoutWidth` to the frame widths? Is that literal? You should set it to the width of the alignment rect. `label.preferredMaxLayoutWidth = [label alignmentRectForFrame:label.frame].size.width;` Does that help?

Comment: I wasn't using alignmentRectForFrame, but after trying it, still no luck.

Comment: I created a Github project; everything is in there. If anything, I really hope I'm doing something wrong because I just want this working. https://github.com/gbrhaz/BrokenTableViewCells

Comment: Did you already solve your problem?